# XCode: Memory Leak When Performing Modal Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uistoryboardsegue

When a logged in user opens my application, they are sent to the main TabBarController from my AppDelegate, like so:

```
UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
tabBar.selectedIndex = 2; 
// (this is MainViewController in the tab bar)
```

Now, the user is in MainViewController. When the user selects a particular chat they'd like to enter, they are sent to the ChatViewController (not on the TabBarController), like so:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showChatSeg" sender:self];

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:ChatViewController.class]){
        ChatViewController *destinationViewController = (ChatViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

        if(self.createdDialog != nil){
            destinationViewController.dialog = self.createdDialog;
            self.createdDialog = nil;
        }else{
            QBChatDialog *dialog = [ChatService shared].dialogs[self.selectedChat];
            destinationViewController.dialog = dialog;
        }
    }
}
```

When this happens, I see a spike in memory usage, which makes sense. However, when the user leaves the ChatViewController and return to the MainViewController, like so:

```
- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {  
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromChatToDashSeg" sender:nil];   

// This is a storyboard segue back to the MainTabBarController

}
```

I get the following warning:

```
Attempt to present <MainTabBarController: 0x17ef28d0> on <ChatViewController: 0x17d6c940> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

And the memory usage remains the same. And when the user enters a chat again, the memory continues to increase. Am I not dismissing the sending view controllers properly?

Comment: Are you using a modal segue to present the chat? Instead of using a segue to go back. Try calling [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is not going "back" but rather, you are presenting a copy of the previous view on top of the one you already have. That's why memory is building up, because you just keep stacking more and more views on top of eachother. Assuming you are using a modal segue to present your chat view, try calling:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Using this, I still get the notice: Attempt to present <MainTabBarController: 0x155c5210> on <ChatViewController: 0x156b8680> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: And the memory issues remain.

Comment: Where did you define the fromChatToDashSeg? Is that in your storyboard? Delete the segue just to make sure that it's still not somehow using the segue instead of properly dismissing.

Comment: thanks, that was it. also, as a note, I realized that my tableView wasn't being released in the ChatViewController, so I had to manually do that in - (void) dealloc { }

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to perform a segue just to get back to your original location. All you need to do is dismiss your current modal view controller by calling `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`. Whenever you add a modal view to the view stack you want to call this method to exit, unless your intent is to add yet another view on top of the modal.